# Are scripts automatically executed when they are included?

Tags: php

If I have a php script and I use the "include" keyword so I can access another script, does the script that I "include" automatically executed?

Comment: Yes! otherwise you couldn't use a variable when you assign it in the file which you include! (I think you want to store the code from the file in function's so you can call them if you need)

Comment: Yes, the script gets parsed and executed.

Comment: Please read the documentation! Simple one-click Google to find http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php.

Answer (score 1):

Include is pretty simple. It just includes the file as if the code was right there. Including another file is just like copying the content and pasting it directly into the file in which it is included.

**file1.php**

```
<?php
    echo "this is from file1";
?>
```

**file2.php**

```
<?php
    include "file1.php";
    echo "this is from file2";
?>
```

This is the exact equivalent to:

```
<?php
    echo "this is from file1";
    echo "this is from file2";
?>
```

So yes, the included script does get executed - but not separately. It is merged with the code from the including file and everything is executed together.

Answer (score 0):

Include acts as if the content of the given file is placed there.

If the file to which you refer only contains `class` and `function` defitions, evidently they are not executed. If they contain commands, they are.